# How to find all texts list that is used multiple times in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I tried to find all texts list that I used several times in a cell.

**Example:**

> My name is Ayesha Akter & Sumon is my boyfriend. Sumon called me just Ayesha.

**Result will be:**

> My | Ayesha | is

I tried using String & Substring but, it's only displaying result of some specific text that I given substring. This is the formula I tried.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1,$A2)),$B$1,"")
```

Comment: you would need a source value that you were checking for. If you only care about more than once then do search starting at position 1 and if found restart start at that position plus 1. if that returns isnumber then bingo.\

Comment: that would be for a single string btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim e           As Variant
Dim nStr        As String
Dim txt         As String
Dim r           As Long

For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(r, 1).Value = "" Then Cells(r, 2).Value = ""
    nStr = Replace(Cells(r, 1).Value, ".", ""): txt = ""

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = 1
        For Each e In Split(nStr, " ")
            .Item(Trim$(e)) = .Item(Trim$(e)) + 1
        Next e
        For Each e In .keys
            If .Item(e) > 1 Then
                txt = txt & " | " & e
            End If
        Next e
    End With

    Cells(r, 2).Value = Mid$(txt, 3)
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: wow! This code works fine but only for Active Cell. Is it possible for all cell in a column?

Comment: I have edited the code to make you able to use loops.